# How to show cell's carriage return as new line?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to define a `CSS` class which would substitute the component's text's carriage returns (as coming from the DB, for example) with `<br/>` so that they are displayed as new line?

Currently, I have a table whose one field is a user entered note they enter in a popup form.  They can make paragraphs in the `textarea` and the data loaded in the form text area for editing shows proper new lines but when it is updated and the popup closed, the main page's data table naturally does not convert the new line carriage return into new HTML line.  My question is is there a way to do it via CSS?

I am using CSS `word-wrap: break-word` to display the note content in my table cell so that it wraps text into the new line within the cell, however, it does not do it for user entered new lines using 
, which are BTW stored and retrieved fine in the DB.

Comment: use `<pre>`, which forces the browser to honor `\n` as if it was `<br>`

Comment: but then i will lose the text wrapping into the new line

Comment: You can have one or the other. Not both.

Comment: OK, so i can't do what i was hoping to do

Comment: then what you want is not possible with css. `<pre>` or `white-space: pre` will give you the line-break-as-br, but then also disable line wrapping for the rest of the text. you should process the text yourself, then, e.g. php's `nl2br()`

Answer (score 6):

Might be a little late, but following up on Marc B's comment at the end, if you use `white-space: pre-line` or `white-space: pre-wrap` that seems to preserve line breaks and line wrapping at the same time.

- `pre-line`: Collapses multiple sequences of white space
- `pre-wrap`: Preserves multiple sequences of white space

MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: For example: "<p style='white-space: pre-line;'> [Text from DB with carriage returns. ]</p>" will work. This answers the question and I think this should be marked as accepted.